# Creating a resource that belongs_to another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, controller

Here are my relevant models:

```
class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :inventory_item
    belongs_to  :shopping_list
    belongs_to  :item
end

class ShoppingList < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :list_items
    belongs_to  :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
end

class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :item, :foreign_key => :item_id
    belongs_to  :vendor
    has_many    :list_items
end
```

I want to have a button to create `ListItems` that belong to a user specified list that they own. The new `ListItem` also needs to be passed the respective `:item_id` and `:inventory_item_id`. Here's the relevant part of my current view:

```
<tr>
        <% item.inventory_items.each do |product| %>
        <td><%= button_to "#{product.price}",
                           {:controller => :list_items,
                            :action => 'create',
                            :id => #what goes here??,
                            :method => :create %></td>
        <% end %>
</tr>
```

And my ListItems controller create method:

```
def create
        ListItem.create
        flash[:success] = "List Item Added."
        redirect_to search_results_path(params[:search])
end
```

Clearly my create method isn't all that useful right now because it just creates a ListItem with no attributes other than `:id`. What's the best way to pass the appropriate parameters to my controller? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bunch of snooping around SO etc. I think the best way to accomplish this is to use a form with hidden fields, as below:

```
<%= form_tag("/list_items", method: "post") do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:item_id, item.id) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:inventory_item_id, product.id) %> 
<%= hidden_field_tag(:shopping_list_id, ShoppingList.first.id) %>
<%= submit_tag("#{product.price}") %>
```

This is working well for me and is cleaner in this instance than using a `button_to`.